# wrong value coming when adding values using ternary operator in java

Tags: java, conditional-operator

The value of sum is not changing even if I am adding it inside the for loop. Value of diff is 3

The value which is getting printed is like 3 3 3 in initial iteration which should be 3 6 9.
Can someone please help?

```
     loop start           
     sum = sum + diff<(26-diff)?diff:(26-diff);
     loop end
```

Comment: Can you add the exact code with which we can reproduce the scenario

Comment: Use brackets around `diff<(26-diff)` to make it clear that you don't want the expression `sum + diff` as part of the compare operator. Or use `sum += diff<....`.

Comment: What language is this? It certainly doesn't look like Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of precedence in how your numeric expression is being calculated is what's causing you to get the wrong result.  Your current statement is equivalent to this:

```
sum = (sum + diff)<(26-diff)?diff:(26-diff);
```

and so equates to the value of `diff`, which is always `3`.  Change your statement to this:

```
sum = sum + (diff<(26-diff)?diff:(26-diff));
```

and you'll get the behavior you're expecting. you can also use the `+=` operator to fix this by changing your statement to:

```
sum += diff<(26-diff)?diff:(26-diff);
```